# Post not working correctly with JavaScript dynamically created textboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I have never tried to post dynamic textboxes created with javascript to process the data. The only form data that is being sent to the processing page is the submit button value. Any ideas on how to do this so that all textbox data sent through post correctly?

Page Code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['saleid'])) {
    header('location: dashboard.php');
    die();
}else{
    include('db_connect.php');
    $saleid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['saleid']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' })

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>5){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    $("#sale > tbody").append("<tr><td> <label>Date:</label><br /><input type='textbox' id='date" + counter + "' ></td><td> <label>Type:</label><br /><input type='textbox' id='type" + counter + "' ></td><td> <label>Amount:</label><br /><input type='textbox' id='amount" + counter + "' ></td><td><label>Notes:</label><br /><input type='textbox' id='notes" + counter + "' ></td></tr>");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter<3){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $('#sale tr:last').remove();
   })
     });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo "Sale ID: ". $saleid; ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo "process_saletrans.php?saleid=" . $saleid; ?>">
<h2>Sale Transaction</h2>
          <table id="sale" width="300" border="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
              <td> <label>Date:</label><br />
            <input type='textbox' id='date1' ></td>
              <td> <label>Type:</label><br />
            <input type='textbox' id='type1' ></td>
            <td> <label>Amount:</label><br />
            <input type='textbox' id='amount1' ></td>
            <td> <label>Notes:</label><br />
            <input type='textbox' id='notes1' ></td>
      </table>
    <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton'>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Transaction" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is that you're using `id` rather than `name`. You can use `id` at the same time, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't set the name of the form field for purposes of submitting the form.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to create this so it does or pull the values in jquery and pass along as an array?

Comment: All you need to do is set the `name` properties of each of these `input` elements to the same value you're currently setting their `id` properties to.

Comment: You could just change `id` to `name`, but you might want to keep `id` as well if you're using it for styling. Presumably not the case for at least the dynamically generated ones though, so... Just go ahead and change all the `id`s to `name`.